# Developing a FreeCAD Plugin Using PyFlow: Issues with Python Interpreter and Module Import

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, freecad

I'm working on developing a plugin for FreeCAD that leverages the PyFlow library. To clarify and avoid an XYZ problem, I aim to create a FreeCAD plugin using PyFlow.

For development, I face a dilemma:

- I can't find the Freecad module using a separate Python interpreter when installing it via pip.
- Using FreeCAD's bundled Python interpreter, I seem to successfully install packages (like PyFlow) using FreeCAD's pip. However, I can't locate the installed Pyflow folder, nor can I import PyFlow within the interpreter.

FreeCAD's Python interpreter apparently installs packages to a location I cannot determine. I've tried checking the site-packages directory, but the Pyflow folder isn't present.

Has anyone experienced similar issues, or can you offer guidance on correctly setting up the environment for developing a FreeCAD plugin using external libraries like PyFlow?

the `pip install freecad` retunrs

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement freecad (from versions: none)
>  ERROR: No matching distribution found for freecad

I checked the folders:

```
C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages
C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.20\bin\Lib\site-packages
```

I see the folder `pyflow-0.3.1.dist-info`, but it does not contain the relevant files, such as an `__init__.py` file or a PyFlow subdirectory.

I tried purging with

```
"C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.20\bin\python.exe" -m pip cache purge
```

and reinstalling with

```
"C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.20\bin\python.exe" -m pip install --force-reinstall pyflow
```

that returns

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
>  Collecting pyflow
>   Using cached pyflow-0.3.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (5.3 MB)
>  Installing collected packages: pyflow
>  Successfully installed pyflow-0.3.1

Comment: @brddawg check [this post](https://forum.freecad.org/viewtopic.php?p=719585&sid=58a440a5b013cceb14479c498c34e7e1#p719585) I wrote after I asked this question.